# Get eligible and active members of an azure ad group with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

In our company we assign group membership through PIM. How can I get all members of a group, both eligible and active?

Tried using

```html
Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId "<groupID>"
```

but this returns more than 100 results, while the group has only one eligible and one active member.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a guy in another forum, this is the correct answer:
Get-MgIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentSchedule
Get-MgIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupEligibilitySchedule